# elixir phoenix introducing pipeline browser variable

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

I have a question around elixir syntax and specifically when it is applied to phoenix.  Considering the following two lines

```
  defmodule HelloWeb.Router do
     pipeline :browser do - (1)
  end
```

Where does the atom `:browser` in line `(1)` come from?  Is it defined in the `HelloWeb` module somewhere, I did a search but could not find it.

Also is this defining a new variable/atom `:browser`. I think its creating a new instance of something, but don't exactly understand what is going on.

Also I have the following

```
  scope "/", HelloWeb do
    pipe_through :browser  -- (2)

    get "/", PageController, :index       
  end
```

Considering line `(2)` its using whatever that got defined in line `(1)`.  So I think line `(1)` is introducing something but not sure what exactly.

Comment: `:browser` is likely a constant/atom used as an input parameter  that gets matched by another `:browser` deep in the macro's function calls.  As long as it matched it doesn't need to take on a value - it will be unique because it is an atom.  I think.

Answer (score 1):

As it could be easily seen from [the source code](https://github.com/phoenixframework/phoenix/blob/v1.6.15/lib/phoenix/router.ex#L627-L671) (which is linked from docs for [`Phoenix.Router.pipeline/2`](https://hexdocs.pm/phoenix/Phoenix.Router.html#pipeline/2),) `pipeline/2` is a macro that injects the following code inplace (I omitted checks and simplified the code a bit):

```elixir
plug = unquote(plug) # :browser
@phoenix_pipeline []
unquote(block)       # do … end content

Scope.pipeline(__MODULE__, plug)
{conn, body} = # builds the plug code
  Plug.Builder.compile(
    __ENV__,
    @phoenix_pipeline,
    init_mode: Phoenix.plug_init_mode())

# def browser(conn, _), do: body
def unquote(plug)(unquote(conn), _) do
  unquote(body) # plug actual code
end
```

That’s it. Further investigation might be done by amending the [elixir](/questions/tagged/elixir) code with `IO.inspect/2` calls and watching the output of the compilation process.